# Jewish Meditation for Soul Travel?

Tags: travel, soul

I know that there is meditation and practices for a soul to transcend the body. I have found these meditations across many religions, however, I am wondering if Judaism has a specific meditation for soul travel?

Comment: what is "soul travel"? Where is the soul traveling to?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36865/discussion-between-eli-and-double-aa).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is indeed a Jewish tradition of meditation. An authentic perspective has been codified by R Aryeh Kaplan in

- [Jewish Meditation: A Practical Guide](http://amzn.com/0805210377)
- [Meditation and the Bible](http://amzn.com/0877286175) (full text seems online [here](http://www.slideshare.net/Tattvamasisatchitananda/aryeh-kaplan-meditation-and-the-bible))
- [Meditation and Kabbalah](http://amzn.com/0877286167) (full text seems online [here](http://www.scribd.com/doc/111152031/Aryeh-Kaplan-1982-Meditation-and-Kabbalah#scribd))

See R Kaplan himself in a rare video clip [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sf4-3QCn3Uw).

See also more [here](http://www.chabad.org/kabbalah/article_cdo/aid/380387/jewish/Active-vsPassive-Meditation.htm) and [here](http://www.chabad.org/kabbalah/article_cdo/aid/380601/jewish/Soul-Meditation.htm) from Chabad.

Comment: I see nothing in this answer about soul tourism.

Comment: @msh210 soul travel is not really defined - I took it as a shortcut for the first part of the question, i.e., "for a soul to transcend the body." Jewish meditation describes certain practices to achieve this